# C# Assembly.LoadWithPartialName non neutral culture

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, .net-assembly

I have two resource files : Resource.resx and Resource.fr.resx.

I want to be able to load resources in both english and french by using `Assembly.LoadWithPartialName`

Can I load french resources which are in `.\fr\Resource.resx` by using `Assembly.LoadWithPartialName`?

Edit 1:

I am currently using :

```
var resMgr = new ResourceManager("Currency.Strings", assembly);
result = resMgr.GetString("Romania", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr"));
```

Which will not bring anything but the neutral language translation.

Comment: Why do you want to use LoadWithPartialName? And are you just loading the strings for translation?

Comment: Yes I want to be able to get resource string i18n without changing culture of the ui thread.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Are you using Silverlight? or just a plain console application?

Comment: I am just building a WCF REST service with i18n for mobile clients.

Comment: Ok. The reason I asked is in silverlight you have to explicitly add the cultures to the silverlight file so the extra resources get added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx#retrieving) to get convenient access to embedded resources with the `ResourceManager`.

Basically, with the convention, `Resource.resx Resource.fr.resx`, you can create a `ResourceManager` looking at Resource and when you change the current thread's culture to 'fr' then the resource manager starts pulling the strings from the second resource.

Comment: I'll try this approach too. If it works, you'll have a surprise.